# How do I mock non overridden, virtual/non virtual methods of a base class while unit testing?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

How do I mock non-overridden non virtual/virtual methods in a base class and test just the derived class's methods?
The case here is:
I have a base class X which has methods that connect to an external server and do a couple of other things.
I have a class Y derived from X. I have implemented two methods in Y. I want to just unit test them. I am worried only about these two methods and I don't want the base class implementation to be called to  connect to the server etc( I want to mock those methods out , but i don't want to override those methods in my derived class Y and do nothing in them, since it is production code). 
Any thoughts /ideas on how can I unit test my those methods in isolation?

P.S: I am using C++/GTest for development and unit testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to create a Mock_base class and the class Derived inheriting from it in the test directory. Now mock out any implementations in the actual Base that you are not interested in with functions that do nothing. Example the Mock_base::Connect() may return SUCCESS  return code. This way you can unit test the Derived:funcs() without modifying the source code.

Comment: Good idea, or make `Derived` a template class inheriting from it's template argument: `template<typename Base> Y : public Base {...`.

Answer (score 3):

You're really lucky you are having a hard time doing this!

Functionality is most of the time not intended to be reused through inheritance, and this is one good reason for that: your base class implements some interface that you want to mock out for a *client* (i.e. Y).  Possibly, this functionality may later be implemented by some other class, too, and Y should be able to use *that* new, possibly better, implementation.

Y *has/uses an* X, but Y *is not an* X.

If your Y class needs to *use* X's functionality (connect to server etc...), it should *aggregate* it, not inherit from it.

You'll notice that the aggregation scheme allows for mocking just like that.